# Azure Kubernetes : Azure Disks or Azure Files as data volumes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have an Azure Kubernetes cluster and I need to mount a data volume for an application like mentioned below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec: 
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate 
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: mysql
    spec: 
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:5.6
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom: 
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-db-password
                  key: db-password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql    
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql    
            - name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script
              mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d                 
      volumes: 
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: azure-managed-disk-pvc
        - name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script
          configMap:
            name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script
```

I see that there are two options to create the Persistent Volume - either a based on Azure Disks or Azure Files.

I want to know what is the difference between Azure Disks or Azure Files with respect to Persistent Volume in Azure Kubernetes and when should I Azure Disks vs Azure Files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something as mysql (exclusive access to files) you are better off using Azure Disks. That would be pretty much a regular disk attached to the pod, whereas Azure Files are mostly meant to be used when you need `ReadWriteMany` access, not `ReadWriteOnce`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-storage